# stopping a service in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I have a problem it seems I cannot stop a service that the main activity starts!

the service:

```
public class Player extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Buffering...Please wait!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        String url = "...";
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        toast.show();
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });




    }       
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Service stoped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast2.show();
    }
```

the activity:

```
public class LoungeRadioActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Tryng to stop service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


        Button on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        on.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(LoungeRadioActivity.this, Player.class));

            }
        });
        Button off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        off.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            toast.show();
            stopService(new Intent(LoungeRadioActivity.this, Player.class));    

            }
        });

    }  
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflate = getMenuInflater();
    inflate.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu );

    return true;
}
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    else {
        stopService(new Intent(LoungeRadioActivity.this, Player.class));
        finish();
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The service never stops?

Comment: yes the service starts and the music plays, but i cant stop the service only thru settings>applications>running>show cached process> stop

Answer (score 0):

try using bindService and tell the service to stop the music from there instead .

also , don't forget to call unbindService